# STD function to return the first iterator where a subsequence begins

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, std, subsequence

Is there a way to return a distance between the first iterator of a sequence, which yields the start of a subsequence in case it is contained within the sequence?

I know [there is](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/includes) `std::includes` which returns `true` if a sequence is a subsequence of another. And it can take a `Compare` object.
My first guess was to have an object to increment a captured iterator (inside a lambda) every time the start of a subsequence is found.
But then I realized that both sequences must be sorted, and a `Compare` object must return `true` on `a < b`.

Can this be done using the std algorithms library?

Comment: Just checking: your sequences are sorted?

Comment: @MarcGlisse no. I am searching for the iterator of the received byte array, where the message header starts.

Comment: What does "the first iterator of a sequence, which yields the start of a subsequence in case it is contained within the sequence" mean? It would help if you provide a clear, concise example of what you're looking for.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Jarod42 has answered. I meant that I need to find an iterator of a sequence, where the subsequence begins if it is contained within. `std::search` seems to be what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are looking for [std::search](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search).